# procedure taking too much time to update the database

Tags: oracle, procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_CRDT_JV IS
 BEGIN
   UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION
         SET GL_DATE = (SELECT ADJ_DATE FROM ADJUSTMENTS WHERE
         ADJ_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
   WHERE TR_TYPE = 'ADJST';
   UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION 
         SET GL_DATE = (SELECT PARTY_ADJ_DATE FROM PARTY_ADJUSTMENT
         WHERE PARTY_ADJ_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
   WHERE TR_TYPE = 'PRTAJ';
   UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION
         SET GL_DATE = (SELECT VEN_PAY_VOU_DATE FROM PAYMENTS_TO_VENDORS WHERE
         VEN_PAY_VOU_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
   WHERE TR_TYPE = 'CRPAY';
   UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION
         SET GL_DATE = (SELECT CHEQUE_DATE FROM SYS_PAYMENTS_HEADER WHERE
         REF_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
   WHERE TR_TYPE = 'SYSPY';
   UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION
         SET GL_DATE = (SELECT POSTED_DATE FROM PURCHASE_INVOICE_HEADER WHERE
         POSTED_DATE IS NOT NULL AND PIV_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
   WHERE TR_TYPE = 'CRINV';
   UPDATE GL_dISTRIBUTION
     SET GL_dATE = (SELECT DOC_dATE FROM REVERSE_HISTORY
           WHERE TR_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(GL_DISTRIBUTION.TR_NUMBER)
         AND DOC_dATE IS NOT NULL AND TR_TYPE IN ('SYSPY','CRPAY'))
         WHERE TR_TYPE IN ('RSYSPY','RCRPAY');
   commit;
   UPDATE_INV_DET;
 END;
```

is taking more than 15 minutes to update the database.
now i am updating this by using the following query in SQL PLUS:

```
EXECUTE UPDATE_CRDT_JV;
```

pls help me if any body knows the solution for this problem

Comment: How are we supposed to know which update is the problem?  Do more work first.  Try some basic logging to output start/end times to identify the problematic update(s), and tell us why you think the update runtime for these are unreasonably slow

Comment: I formatted the code for you.  It is very easy - just select the code and press the {} button above the editor

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the already given advice to start figuring out where your code is spending time. However, your case is quite common and I *think* I recognize this situation: you have coded your update statements in such a way that the other tables are accessed for every row of GL_DISTRIBUTION of that type.

The solution is to rewrite your update statements and I see two possibilities to do that efficiently:

1) Update a select statement (UPDATE (SELECT ...) SET ... WHERE ...). This requires some unique key constraints to be in place or using the BYPASS_UJVC hint.

2) Use a MERGE statement.

Below you see an example of how to rewrite your code using a single merge statement. I'm expecting big performance gains because the access of the other tables is now done once using a single outer join for each of the tables, instead of for every row in the GL_DISTRIBUTION table.

The example.  Test data:

```
SQL> create table gl_distribution (tr_number, tr_type, gl_date)
  2  as
  3  select '1', 'ADJST', date '2011-01-01' from dual union all
  4  select '2', 'ADJST', null from dual union all
  5  select '3', 'PRTAJ', date '2011-01-01' from dual union all
  6  select '4', 'SYSPY', date '2011-01-01' from dual union all
  7  select '5', 'RCRPAY', date '2011-01-01' from dual
  8  /

Table created.

SQL> create table adjustments (adj_number, adj_date)
  2  as
  3  select 1, sysdate from dual union all
  4  select 2, sysdate from dual
  5  /

Table created.

SQL> create table party_adjustment (party_adj_number, party_adj_date)
  2  as
  3  select 3, sysdate from dual union all
  4  select 33, sysdate from dual
  5  /

Table created.

SQL> create table payments_to_vendors (ven_pay_vou_number, ven_pay_vou_date)
  2  as
  3  select 34, sysdate from dual
  4  /

Table created.

SQL> create table sys_payments_header (ref_number,cheque_date)
  2  as
  3  select 4, sysdate from dual
  4  /

Table created.

SQL> create table purchase_invoice_header (piv_number,posted_date)
  2  as
  3  select 35, sysdate from dual
  4  /

Table created.

SQL> create table reverse_history (tr_number,doc_date,tr_type)
  2  as
  3  select 5, sysdate, 'CRPAY' from dual
  4  /

Table created.
SQL>
```

Your procedure (for comparison):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_CRDT_JV
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION
  5    SET GL_DATE = (SELECT ADJ_DATE FROM ADJUSTMENTS WHERE  ADJ_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
  6    WHERE TR_TYPE = 'ADJST'
  7    ;
  8    UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION
  9    SET GL_DATE = (SELECT PARTY_ADJ_DATE FROM PARTY_ADJUSTMENT
 10    WHERE PARTY_ADJ_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
 11    WHERE TR_TYPE = 'PRTAJ'
 12    ;
 13    UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION
 14    SET GL_DATE = (SELECT VEN_PAY_VOU_DATE FROM PAYMENTS_TO_VENDORS
 15    WHERE VEN_PAY_VOU_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
 16    WHERE TR_TYPE = 'CRPAY'
 17    ;
 18    UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION
 19    SET GL_DATE = (SELECT CHEQUE_DATE FROM SYS_PAYMENTS_HEADER WHERE
 20    REF_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
 21    WHERE TR_TYPE = 'SYSPY'
 22    ;
 23    UPDATE GL_DISTRIBUTION
 24    SET GL_DATE = (SELECT POSTED_DATE FROM PURCHASE_INVOICE_HEADER WHERE
 25    POSTED_DATE IS NOT NULL AND PIV_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
 26    WHERE TR_TYPE = 'CRINV'
 27    ;
 28    UPDATE GL_dISTRIBUTION
 29    SET GL_dATE = (SELECT DOC_dATE FROM REVERSE_HISTORY
 30    WHERE TR_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(GL_DISTRIBUTION.TR_NUMBER)
 31    AND DOC_dATE IS NOT NULL AND TR_TYPE IN ('SYSPY','CRPAY'))
 32    WHERE TR_TYPE IN ('RSYSPY','RCRPAY')
 33    ;
 34    --commit;
 35    --UPDATE_INV_DET;
 36  END;
 37  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

My suggestion:

```
SQL> create procedure new_update_crdt_jv
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    merge into gl_distribution d
  5    using ( select to_number(d.tr_number) tr_number
  6                 , coalesce
  7                   ( a.adj_date
  8                   , pa.party_adj_date
  9                   , pv.ven_pay_vou_date
 10                   , sph.cheque_date
 11                   , pih.posted_date
 12                   , rh.doc_date
 13                   ) new_date
 14              from gl_distribution d
 15                   left outer join adjustments a
 16                     on to_number(d.tr_number) = a.adj_number
 17                     and d.tr_type = 'ADJST'
 18                   left outer join party_adjustment pa
 19                     on to_number(d.tr_number) = pa.party_adj_number
 20                     and d.tr_type = 'PRTAJ'
 21                   left outer join payments_to_vendors pv
 22                     on to_number(d.tr_number) = pv.ven_pay_vou_number
 23                     and d.tr_type = 'CRPAY'
 24                   left outer join sys_payments_header sph
 25                     on to_number(d.tr_number) = sph.ref_number
 26                     and d.tr_type = 'SYSPY'
 27                   left outer join purchase_invoice_header pih
 28                     on to_number(d.tr_number) = pih.piv_number
 29                     and d.tr_type = 'CRINV'
 30                   left outer join reverse_history rh
 31                     on to_number(d.tr_number) = rh.tr_number
 32                     and rh.tr_type in ('SYSPY','CRPAY')
 33                     and d.tr_type in ('RSYSPY','RCRPAY')
 34          ) n
 35       on ( d.tr_number = n.tr_number)
 36     when matched then
 37          update set d.gl_date = n.new_date
 38    ;
 39  end new_update_crdt_jv;
 40  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Let's run your procedure:

```
SQL> select * from gl_distribution
  2  /

T TR_TYP GL_DATE
- ------ -------------------
1 ADJST  01-01-2011 00:00:00
2 ADJST
3 PRTAJ  01-01-2011 00:00:00
4 SYSPY  01-01-2011 00:00:00
5 RCRPAY 01-01-2011 00:00:00

5 rows selected.

SQL> exec update_crdt_jv

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from gl_distribution
  2  /

T TR_TYP GL_DATE
- ------ -------------------
1 ADJST  31-03-2011 14:41:19
2 ADJST  31-03-2011 14:41:19
3 PRTAJ  31-03-2011 14:41:19
4 SYSPY  31-03-2011 14:41:19
5 RCRPAY 31-03-2011 14:41:19

5 rows selected.

SQL> rollback
  2  /

Rollback complete.

SQL>
```

My procedure returns the same results:

```
SQL> exec new_update_crdt_jv

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from gl_distribution
  2  /

T TR_TYP GL_DATE
- ------ -------------------
1 ADJST  31-03-2011 14:41:19
2 ADJST  31-03-2011 14:41:19
3 PRTAJ  31-03-2011 14:41:19
4 SYSPY  31-03-2011 14:41:19
5 RCRPAY 31-03-2011 14:41:19

5 rows selected.
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: I tweaked the layout so we can see the results without scrolling.  +1 BTW

Comment: Nicely done, APC! Although my answer now takes up a lot of space :-)

Answer (score 3):

The solution for this problem is:

1. Figure out where your code is
   spending its time (i.e. profile it)
2. Figure out how to speed up the
   slowest part
3. Repeat until performance is acceptable

If you prefer guesswork, then you might want to try any of the following:

Combine multiple UPDATEs into a single UPDATE statement, e.g. using a CASE condition as shown by @Aklopper.

Use MERGE instead of UPDATE to avoid correlated subqueries.  Might be better, might not.

Look into the UPDATE_INV_DET procedure which is called at the end of the procedure shown.

Answer (score 2):

I come from a SQL Server environment, won't a CASE UPDATE statement like this also help you(example of usage of the UPDATE CASE statement in SQL(don't know if Oracle has an equivalent methods) :

```
   UPDATE titles
           SET GL_DATE=
                     CASE
                       WHEN TR_TYPE = 'ADJST' THEN (SELECT ADJ_DATE FROM ADJUSTMENTS WHERE ADJ_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER) END
                       WHEN TR_TYPE = 'PRTAJ'' THEN (SELECT PARTY_ADJ_DATE FROM PARTY_ADJUSTMENT
         WHERE PARTY_ADJ_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(TR_NUMBER))
 END
                       ELSE price
                     END
```

Comment: Yes, Oracle supports the same CASE construct. It's possible that the query could be optimized a lot more - but further refinement would be guesswork without seeing the structure and pattern of the data.

Comment: DEAR AKLOPPER,  i tried this but showing same error. after 15 min,I got report from server. I give UPDATE_INV_DET Procedure below: